# Можно ли в iptables проверить соединение на длительность по времени?

Tags: linux, iptables

Вот например, у меня есть правило:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
```

Но я хочу добавить условие, чтобы это правило срабатывало, если время жизни соединения меньше 30 секунд. Под временем жизни я подразумеваю время от момента открытия соединения. Я работаю с tcp.

Comment: нет. вы можете ограничить в какое время могут подключиться, скажем, по будням с 8.00 по 18.00,  но не сможете длительность ограничить, если конечно с 2013 года ничего не изменилось

Comment: кажется, я ошибся. есть флаги `-m limit --limit 10/minute` , в вашем случае будет `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state INVALID -m limit --limit 10/minute -j DROP `

Comment: `--limit 30/sec`

Comment: @SeniorPomidor я знаком с этим модулем limit. это не то, что я хочу. через этот модуль можно ограничить частоту пакетов. я же хочу не частоту, а ограничение по времени с момента открытия открытия соединения. например, первые 10 минут пропускать пакет, а после 10 минут не пропускать больше никогда

Comment: Скрипи напишите крторые чекает записии каждую минуту по крону потом меняет цепочку на блокирующую

Comment: Я бы сказал, что это дело прикладного уровня. Но есть у модуля conntrack некий --ctexpire. Не оно? Если не оно, а очень хочется именно через iptables, то всегда есть NFQUEUE.